# Sending Email with attachment in html format

Tags: php, html, html-table, html-email, email-attachments

I have PHP code that sends email with attachment but what I want is to put all the data like Full Name, Contact Number, etc into a table. I tried using `<table>` but the email is still a plain text. Can someone help me how to make it?

This is my php code:

```
<?php
 $cname = $_POST['Name'];
 $cnumber = $_POST['Tel'];
 $cemail = $_POST['emailadd'];
 $cmess = $_POST['contactmess'];
 $index = 'index.php';

 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"] , "/files/upload/" .  $_FILES["attachment"]["name"]);

 $to = 'peace@gmail.com'; 
 $subject = 'Careers Inquiry';  
 $random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
 $headers = "From: ". $cemail ."\r\nReply-To:". $cemail; 
 $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset='iso-8859-1'";
 $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents("/files/upload/" .$_FILES["attachment"]["name"]))); 

 ob_start();
?>
--PHP-mixed-`<?php echo $random_hash; ?> ` 
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-`<?php echo $random_hash; ?>`" 

--PHP-alt-`<?php echo $random_hash; ?>`  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

--PHP-alt-`<?php echo $random_hash; ?>`
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Name: </td><td><?php echo $cname; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Contact Number: </td><td><?php echo $cnumber; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email Address: </td><td><?php echo $cemail; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Message: </td><td><?php echo $cmess; ?></td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>

--PHP-alt-`<?php echo $random_hash; ?>`-- 

--PHP-mixed-`<?php echo $random_hash; ?>`  
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="`<?php echo $_FILES["attachment"]["name"];?>`"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
Content-Disposition: attachment  

`<?php echo $attachment; ?>` 
--PHP-mixed-`<?php echo $random_hash; ?>`--

<?php
$message = ob_get_clean();
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 
unlink('/files/upload/' . $_FILES["attachment"]["name"]);
echo $mail_sent ? header('Location: '. $index): '<script type="text/javascript">       alert("Sorry, service temporary unavailable."); </script>'; 
?>
```

Comment: [Don't reinvent the wheel](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer).

Answer (score 2):

For complex emailing with PHP checkout the [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) class.

It is much easier to send complex emails (e.g. in HTML format) with the functions in PHPMailer.

It is easy to install and use. Look at the examples at the bottom of the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

First up, if you can, pick up a library like:

- [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)
- [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)
- [Pear's Mail_Mime](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime)

All the above have a bit of a learning curve to start, but the long run they will help you immensely.  Getting mail headers and boundaries right so that spam filters don't pick up your mails is a real pain - and other people have solved these problems for you already.

However, if you insist on building the mail manually.

When constructing your headers it'll be easier to read if you split each one onto its own line and ensure that you end with a `\r\n`

E.g.

```
$headers  = "From: $cemail\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $cemail\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"\r\n";
```

It looks like you might have missed a couple of `\r\n` off the last two headers.

Also, you duplicated your Content-Type headers.  The second is not necessary as you specify the Content-Type on each boundary anyway.

charset should not be quoted.

I.E.

`charset='iso-8859-1'` and `charset="iso-8859-1"`

Should be

`charset=iso-8859-1`

It's possible those are your issues.

Running the output through Message Lint (http://www.apps.ietf.org/content/message-lint) doesn't throw up anything particular other than the above.